# Generic list conversion

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I have three classes

```
public class OSiteEquipment : IPlantItem
public class OSiteSubSystem : IPlantItem
public class OSiteComponent : IPlantItem
```

Each implement interface IPlantItem

In my xaml i bind to an Observable collection like

```
public ObservableCollection<IPlantItem> CurrentItems
```

Sometimes i need to bind `CurrentItems` to an collection of OSiteEquipments and sometimes to OSiteSubSystem

If i try to set CurrentItems when i load the view like this

```
CurrentItems = this.siteDocument.Sitestructure.Equipments;
```

Where `Sitestructure.Equipments` is an observable collection of OSiteEquipment, compiler says i cant convert from `Observablecollection<IPlantItem>` to `Observablecollection<OSiteEquipment>`

Is there a way to solve this. DO i need to make an explicit conversion

**EDIT**

Solved it , instead of defining CurrentItems as ObservableCollection  i as

```
object CurrentItems
```

The reason i didnt do it in the beginning was that i thougt i would destroy the notification binding, but it still works fine.

Comment: Why Do you want to avoid the explicit conversion?

Comment: An `Observablecollection<OSiteEquipment>` is not an `Observablecollection<IPlantItem>`. So of course the compiler objects.

Comment: Looks like `ObservableCollection` is not covariant, so an explicit conversion is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit conversion from `ObservableCollection<OSiteEquipment>` to `Observablecollection<IPlantItem>` wouldn't work either. If you wanted this to work, you would need to copy the elements of the `OSiteEquipment` collection to a new `IPlantItem`. But then changes to the original collection wouldn't affect the new collection, so this is not what you want.

You already found a solution, but I think it would be better if you changed the type of `CurrentItems` to `IEnumerable<IPlantItem>`. This shouldn't affect the binding, but it means your code is safer and more self-documenting (it's more obvious what should that property be).